# Childrens' apps hog the bandwidth on home LAN; how to add limits for kids

Tags: linux, networking, bandwidth

At home, we have a small network. We connect laptops using WiFi, provided by a TP-Link router (Model No. [TL-WR1043ND](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/tl-wr1043nd/)). We run Windows and Linux operating systems on those laptops. The problem is our kids are playing network based games which consume bandwidth.

I am here to find out how could I limit them, in one way or another.  I do use Linux but basically I am a DB specialist.

First, I want to count, for a while, how much from this bandwidth is consumed by each distinct URL. This means, I want to gather first URLs, then collect a sort of min/max/avg of bytes or package for each distinct URL. At the end, because I know which IP addresses are used by the players, I want to respond them with a fake 404 or "site banned" response.

For this, is it enough if my Linux is just a normal client of this network or must be a gateway between WLAN and LAN?

KI

Comment: I am surprised that people on superuser.com would downvote such questions... Gave you +1 just in spite of the downvoter who did not leave a comment.

Comment: You probably have bufferbloat rather than a simple lack of bandwidth. Run http://dslreports.com/speedtest from a desktop/laptop web browser and check your bufferbloat grade. If that site doesn't support your country but fast.com does, then use fast.com and check the advanced options to measure latency under load. If you fix your bufferbloat first, you might not need to throttle your kids' traffic.

Answer (score 2):

Install an open-source firmware on the 1043, for example [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/) or one of its derivatives.

If you want to limit bandwidth, the simplest way is to distinguish between the devices the kids are using and your devices, and then implement bandwidth limits or priority rules based on that.

There are several ways to do that; the safest is to give them their own AP with their own SSID and not the password to your AP. But IIRC the 1043 doesn't support multiple APs, so you'd need additional hardware for that.

Another way is to give them specific IPs based on their MAC address; as long as they don't figure out how to configure static IPs or spoof the MAC address, that should work.

As for looking at each URL, that's a lot more difficult, and games may not even use the HTTP/HTTPS protocol. You'd need a webproxy on your 1043, which will consume quite a bit of memory and CPU, and some kind of storage device for the URL database. So while this is doable to some degree, you'd again need additional hardware, and might even brake some of the games they want to play.

If you want to put a dedicated host running 24/7 ("your Linux") between the 1043 and the network, that's also an option - you can do this with proper routing.

Anyhow, if you don't have any networking experience, you'll have to read up on quite a bit of stuff. More than a single answer here can explain.

Comment: http://downloads.openwrt.org/releases/18.06.4/targets/ar71xx/generic/openwrt-18.06.4-ar71xx-generic-tl-wr1043nd-v3-squashfs-factory.bin

Answer (score 2):

**1. About blocking access with "site banned/404":**

One option would be to supervise children laptops with a feature called **Parental Control**. Family Link made by Google works quite well on mobile devices like Android, Chromebooks and iOS. And best of all it is free and can supervise their devices even when they are connected to other WiFi routers. There are Parental Control vendors on Windows too that you just have to look up yourself and experiment to see if they are sufficient for what you are looking for.

Another option, would be to get a WiFi access point that can block access to certain traffic. Depending on vendor this feature is called **Site blocking** or simply **Firewall** or **URL white/black listing**. I am not sure if TL-WR1043ND supports it, but since it appears to be in higher end of price range, then simply login into management console of your router and see if those keywords appear somewhere.

**2. About throttling throughput for children devices, but not completely blocking sites:**

This would have to be set up on Access Point or Gateway. Depending on Access point vendor this feature is called **QoS** or **Priority device** or maybe simply **bandwidth throttling**. Again I would not be surprised that your WiFi access point already supports this and you simply have to configure the feature.

**3. About gathering statistics at URL level**

This one is hardest as most sites use SSL encryption and you don't see the URL. Or children could be using protocols that don't have notion of URL (like Torrents). The best information you could get is just amount of bytes sent between two endpoints and possibly the protocol. There is a feature that goes step beyond and is called **Deep Packet Inspection** or **L7 firewall**, but most consumer grade WiFi access point don't support any of that. You can try to set up a dedicated Linux Access point that acts as Gateway for your children device and set up [Suricata](https://suricata-ids.org/) engine on it. Might be overkill though.